# Input of stepImpl is entire array when using step in a script

Tags: matlab

If I use step(sys,x) in a script after constructing a system object, the entirety of x is passed through as a vector to stepimpl instead of sample by sample input.
On the other hand, if I perform step(sys,s) where s is a scalar instead and iterates this line of code, the state of 'sys' is reset on each call of step.

For example:

```
SFTRLS_obj = SFTRLS;
for i = 1 : N
    step(SFTRLS_obj,d_dx(i),dx(i));
end
```

What is the proper way to use a system object in a script and 'propagate' input samples to the system object?

Answer (score 0):

You should have iteration loop yourselves and call step in the iteration loop. You should use functions if you want to reuse code with System objects. Within the function you should declare System objects as persistent and create it once as shown in the code below. This will create the System objects once and will keep the states in each call to function.

```
function y = useSystemObjects(u)

persistent obj
if isempty(obj)
    % Create System object once
    obj = MySystemObject;
end

y = step(obj, u);
```

% Use the above function from MATLAB command line

```
data = rand(100,1);
y = zeros(100,1);
for n=1:100
  y(ii) = useSystemObjects(data(ii));
end
```

If you use scripts, the object is getting recreated in each call to the script which destroys the states.

Comment: I created my object outside the loop and loop over the function "step" but states didn't keep the values as I checked the debugger. I definitely did not loop over the constructor function of the object.

Comment: See edited question. I just thought it was pretty obvious of what I meant

Comment: There will be only one call to reset the first time step is called. From second iteration states should be preserved. I was looking for System object code to see if there is anything triggering reset call from there.